# Extending apply function to S3 (like with print or plot)

Tags: r, oop, apply, lapply, r-s3

I am working on a [pet project](https://github.com/athompson1991/groupR) in R that builds out a custom S3 class named `groupr`. I have written a few functions with dot notation (`print.groupr`, `subset.groupr`)  as described in the [Hadley tutorial](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/OO-essentials.html), but I would *like* to extend the `apply` function and cannot find a way to do so.

As demonstrated in the tutorial, the `pryr` package provides a hint. I see that the `subset` and `print` function are different function types like so:

```
> pryr::ftype(subset)
[1] "s3"      "generic"
> pryr::ftype(apply)
[1] "function"
```

Additionally, the `subset` function prints this in the terminal:

```
function (x, ...) 
UseMethod("subset")
<bytecode: 0x115f0ab88>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

But the `apply` function prints its entire source code. I *believe* I understand why this is happening - the `print`, `subset`, `plot`, etc functions are S3 functions and `apply` is a boring old normal function - but I don't see any way to extend the `apply` function without "overwriting" the base function. For example, `UseMethod("apply")` points the function call to my `groupr` namespace when the package is loaded.

Does anyone know how to address this? Namely, the family of `apply` functions are not S3 objects and cannot be extended using dot notation. Does anyone know how to write `apply.myclass`, `apply.myotherclass` functions?

Comment: `apply` is not generic. I believe that this is what makes the difference, it should be awkward to write methods to it. Like you say, you would have to *"overwrite" the base function*.

Answer (score 1):

You're mostly there; you do need to overwrite the original `apply`, but do with a generic function that calls the original as the default. So your package would have three functions: `apply`, which would be the new generic, `apply.default`, which would call `base::apply`, and your new `apply.myclass`. When your package is loaded, your version of `apply` would be higher in the search path, so would get used. I'm sure I've seen packages do this but can't put my hands on an example right now.

I would, though, question if this is worth it; will your users really mind that the version for `groupr`'s is `apply_groupr`, for example? We all know what `apply` does and that's used on matrices, is this new functionality really similar enough to share the same name? That is if I see `apply(my_groupr, 2, mean)` will I be confused because `my_groupr` isn't a matrix?

Comment: Cool, I believe that makes sense. My plan is essentially what you describe - give it a different name altogether - because it avoids that search path nonsense. However, it does seem to me that `apply` is general enough that it could be rewritten as an S3 generic function. For example, `apply.matrix`, `apply.list`, `apply.vector` could replace `apply`, `lapply`, and `vapply`. It is all just a vectorized way of looping. I guess this is just the first time I've run into weird idiosyncrasies of R itself (another being the inconsistent application of dot notation, such as with `t.data.frame`)

Comment: Speaking of weird idiosyncrasies of R, have you seen [The R Inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/documents/books/the-r-inferno/)?

Comment: Ahh _that_, yes, I have seen it but have yet to give it a read through. It does seem someone has a sense of humor about this stuff.